# when would I use a shallow copy?

Tags: reference, deep-copy, value-type, shallow-copy

I understand what the difference between a shallow and deep copy are, but I really don't understand in what situations a shallow copy would be preferred.

If I'm not mistaken, shallow copy makes a new copy of the value types and simply copies the address of reference types so they are pointing to the same object, correct?  Why would I ever want this effect?

Comment: Imagine that your type represents a smart pointer (in e.g. C++), or a list (in a functional language like Haskell).  A deep copy is definitely not what you want in these cases.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In fact a shallow copy is the way with least effort, doing less. It is especially suited for **immutable** objects, where sharing is optimal.

An immutable object does not have an *internal state*, cannot be changed, only variables can be set to another value.

In java `String` and `BigDecimal` are immutable.

Immutable objects allow making better use of threads too.

For mutable classes you might be interested in **copy-on-write** data structures, where sharing happens till one variable is written to.

Answer (score 0):

I think one good example could help understanding the concept. Suppose you have a list of tuples. And you the list to a function to process something on. Creating some sub-lists from the original one could help in a function and this is not necessary to **deep-copy** all the tuples in the list. And you just need to copy those pointers (**shallow-copy**).